# Ensuring that sequence of repeated trials does not bias result

Tags: anova, variance, experiment-design, heteroscedasticity, bias

Imagine the following experimental design:

You have four conditions, A,B,C and D, regarding an online platform.  Conditions A,B,C have a different feature enabled that you want to compare and D has none enabled (control).

You have a sample of 18 users interacting with this platform each time posting something there. The activity is executed **one after another**, the newcoming users see what the previous users have posted. You repeat this process for 3 times (3x18=54 for each condition) - starting from the same starting point and each time with a completely new sample (this is not a longitudinal study)

At the end of each activity, you take measurements on several psychometric variables that you will evaluate your features against.

Before you proceed to analyse (with ANOVA or Kruskal-Wallis), how can we verify that the users' activities and interactions between the 18 users within the same group (sequence of messaging, type of content or users comments etc) do not bias the results?
e.g. if a "troll" user posted first did not negatively affect the behaviour of the rest of the users

What statistical test would check this?

Would Levene's test to check homogeneity of variance across the groups of 18 be sufficient? How to proceed if it does pass the test?

Would the simplification, of treating the total of 54 as one big pot, be wrong?

Comment: Hey mate! Interesting question! I don't know the answer but I have some pointers:
1. Look into adaptive trial design, what you're doing is multiple hypothesis testing and adaptive trials do the same. Being Medical trials they tend to be pretty strict on doing good statistics so you might find something useful

Comment: 2. If I understand your question correctly you want to check whether the early comments on each of the 3 starts per feature has some effect? Depending on the context I almost feel like it's safer to assume that it will have an effect, but I'm not qualified to make a definitive comment